# Soundcloud API / SoundManager2 SetPosition not working before track is playing

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I am trying to set the position of a sample in SoundCloud using setPosition to play from a certain time when I call the play() method.  I need to set this before the sample starts playing.  Right now this code isn't working:

```
SC.whenStreamingReady(function() {
            var sound = SC.stream("/tracks/141543551");
            sound.play();
            sound.setPosition(300);
        });
```

However, when I call setPosition while the sample is playing it works just fine.

```
SC.whenStreamingReady(function() {
                setTimeout(function () {

                sound.pause();

                var positionCallback = function (eventPosition) {
                    this.clearOnPosition(0, positionCallback);
                    this.resume();
                };
                sound.onPosition(0, positionCallback);
                sound.setPosition(30000);


                sound.play();

 }, 5000);

    });
```

How can I setPosition() before the sample plays?

Answer (score 1):

The docs that I found here http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/

Say that this `sound.setPosition(300);` should look like `sound.setPosition('position-name', 300);` instead.